# C++/SFML Window creation fail

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, window, sfml

Well, I tried to do everything as shown in [tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/window-window.php), but it just shows console and nothing more. Tried this clock program and it works just fine. I connected all libs, and copied all .dll files, so really don't know where I'm wrong. Please tell me what to do to show make it show window. I'm using VS2010, SFML 1.6 and here's my code.

```
    #include <SFML\Window.hpp>

    int main()
    {

         sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(640, 480, 32), "wut");

         while (App.IsOpened())
         {
              sf::Event Event;
              while (App.GetEvent(Event))
              {
               // Window closed
               if (Event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
                   App.Close();

               // Escape key pressed
               if ((Event.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (Event.Key.Code == sf::Key::Escape))
                  App.Close();        
               };
              App.Display();

          }
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    // Create the main rendering window
    sf::RenderWindow App(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Graphics");

    // Start game loop
    while (App.IsOpened())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event Event;
        while (App.GetEvent(Event))
        {
            // Close window : exit
            if (Event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
                App.Close();
        }

        // Clear the screen (fill it with black color)
        App.Clear();

        // Display window contents on screen
        App.Display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Still it shows only console, and window won't show up. I have neither errors nor warnings in my VS 2010. I need all this as soon as possible. I hope there is a way to make it work, or there is some graphics engine as easy as SMFL (object oriented ofc).

Answer (score 0):

Do you link against sfml-main library?  If not, try that, if that fails, try to do a [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of main() function. Also, make sure that Visual Studio has not set your project to a console program.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using SFML a lot recently. Try these suggestions in order, keeping each previous change:

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

It should be sf::RenderWindow, not sf::Window

It should be `while (App.isOpen())` not IsOpened()

If it doesnt seem to have the function "isOpen" on your RenderWindow , you probably don't have SFML2, which I recommend getting immediately.

Did you rebuild the libraries for your computer, or did you just try and use the .dll's they provide? You may need to rebuild them using Cmake, and whatever your compiler is. I know I did.

Finally, I also recommend using the latest Code::Blocks as your IDE instead, but I guess only switch as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Old question.. but here is my answer: When you sayed; *"I'm using VS2010, SFML 1.6..."*, in the download page says that for sfml-1.6 in Windows, it is possible to use VScode 2005 and VScode 2009. Try to use a different version of Vscode (and link everything to test) and see if it works.

(For me your code looks fine for SFML-1.6, so i don't think that's the problem)